# TestNG assign programatically DataProvider

Tags: java, testng, testng-dataprovider, testng-annotation-test

If I have a method:

```java
@Test(dataProvider = "webTarget")
void testFirst(WebTarget target) {
    // ...
}
```

Can I create a Listener or something in TestNG, that if I have a method:

```java
@Test
void testFirst(WebTarget target) {
    // ...
}
```

then it automatically injects specific dataProvider, without explicitly specifying it `@Test(dataProvider = "webTarget")` ?

Comment: Yes it is possible, only if you are running the test case using a suite file. But it is not clear why you want to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally speaking, the easiest way to go about doing this would be to:

1. Define an abstract class in which you define the required data provider and also the data that your data provider would feed off of, as its source and give it to the test methods (It could be something like the data provider feeds off of an injected value into it)
2. Have your test classes, extend this abstract class and then from within an `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` implementation, you merely inject the data provider method name into the test class.

In case you don't want to use an abstract class also, then here's another alternative. This kind of looks like a round about way of doing it.

For this example, the dependency injection framework that I am using is Guice.

The interfaces that we are going to be using in this example are as below

```java
/**
 * Lets any test class expose the injected values to any caller.
 */
public interface ObjectGetter {

  /**
   * @return - The {@link Student} object that is required.
   */
  Student getStudent();
}
```

```java
/**
 * Allows for setting the actual object to be used by any data provider
 */
public interface ObjectSetter {

  /**
   * @param student - The {@link Student} object
   */
  void setStudent(Student student);
}
```

Here's how the Guice module that we are using in this example looks like

```java
import com.google.inject.Binder;
import com.google.inject.Module;

public class MyLocalGuiceModule implements Module {

  @Override
  public void configure(Binder binder) {
    binder.bind(Student.class).toInstance(new Student(100, "KungFu-Panda"));
  }
}
```

Here's how the test class looks like

```java
import com.google.inject.Inject;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import org.testng.annotations.Guice;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

@Guice(modules = MyLocalGuiceModule.class)
public class SampleTestClass implements ObjectGetter {

  @Inject
  private Student student;

  @Override
  public Student getStudent() {
    return student;
  }

  @Test
  public void testMethod(Student s) {
    String text = s.toString();
    assertThat(text).isEqualTo("Student{id=100, name='KungFu-Panda'}");
  }
}
```

Here's how the separate data provider class would look like

```java
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;

public class DataProviderHouse implements ObjectSetter {

  private Student student;

  @DataProvider(name = "students")
  public Object[][] getStudents() {
    return new Object[][]
        {
            {student}
        };
  }

  @Override
  public void setStudent(Student student) {
    this.student = student;
  }
}
```

The annotation transformer looks like below:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer;
import org.testng.annotations.ITestAnnotation;

public class LocalTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {

  @Override
  public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor,
      Method testMethod) {
    annotation.setDataProviderClass(DataProviderHouse.class);
    annotation.setDataProvider("students");
  }
}
```

The data provider listener looks like below:

```java
import org.testng.IDataProviderListener;
import org.testng.IDataProviderMethod;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;

public class DataProviderListener implements IDataProviderListener {

  @Override
  public void beforeDataProviderExecution(IDataProviderMethod dataProviderMethod,
      ITestNGMethod method, ITestContext iTestContext) {
    Object dpInstance = dataProviderMethod.getInstance();
    if (!(dpInstance instanceof ObjectSetter)) {
      return;
    }
    Object testInstance = method.getInstance();
    if (!(testInstance instanceof ObjectGetter)) {
      return;
    }
    ((ObjectSetter) dpInstance).setStudent(((ObjectGetter) testInstance).getStudent());
  }
}
```

Here's how the suite xml would look like

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="dynamic_data_provider_suite" verbose="2">
  <listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.dynamic.LocalTransformer"/>
    <listener class-name="com.rationaleemotions.dynamic.DataProviderListener"/>
  </listeners>
  <test name="dynamic_data_provider_test" verbose="2">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.rationaleemotions.dynamic.SampleTestClass"/>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here's the chain of events that are expected to happen:

1. The test class uses a Guice Module which injects the required dependencies into the test class.
2. The test class exposes the injected dependency to any caller (data provider listener in this case) via the interface `com.rationaleemotions.dynamic.ObjectGetter`
3. We have an implementation of `org.testng.IAnnotationTransformer` using which we inject a data provider class and a method reference into the test method.
4. The data provider class is a separate class that implements `com.rationaleemotions.dynamic.ObjectSetter` using which it would get hold of the data it should use for data driven tests.
5. We create an implementation of `org.testng.IDataProviderListener` which TestNG provides to eavesdrop into before and after invocation events for data providers. Using this listener we extract out the Guice injected data from the test class and then inject it back into the object to which the data provider belongs to.

This is a bit long way of doing this, but goes a bit more to making the data providers truly dynamic.

Your mileage on using is likely to vary depending upon the actual use case in which you would like to employ such a "sophisticated but yet convoluted approach".

Answer (score 1):

If the data provider methods for each test method are known before hand, then it is possible using `IAnnotationTransformer`. But you need to run your tests using a xml suite file.

**Note**: `Map.of` ([doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V-K-V-)) was introduced in java 9. If you are using a previous version, then you could create the `dpNameMap` using normal hash map.

```java
public class CustomAnnotationTransformer implements IAnnotationTransformer {
    private static final Map<String, String> dpNameMap = Map.of("methodOne", "dataOne",
                                                                "methodTwo", "dataTwo",
                                                                "methodThree", "dataThree");

    @Override
    public void transform(ITestAnnotation annotation, Class testClass, Constructor testConstructor, Method method) {
        if(method != null && dpNameMap.containsKey(method.getName())) {
            annotation.setDataProvider(dpNameMap.get(method.getName()));
        }
    }

}
```

Also add the below in your suite file:

```xml
<listeners>
    <listener class-name="com.yourpackage.CustomAnnotationTransformer" />
</listeners>
```

Comment: Another small question: can I somehow programmatically create a DataProvider and register it with a certain name? To automatically do it for each Test class.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov But how would you generate the data specific to each data provider?

Comment: On test start using a listener.

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov So in the listener, you would be having if conditions to determine the test method and return appropriate data?

Comment: Yep, I will have it)

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov I won't recommend that approach. Instead, you could create a single data provider method, inject the `Method` as parameter and then return appropriate data based on the method name. But, it is always better to keep dedicated data methods for each test case.

Comment: The idea is that I should always have and "object" that should be available by default, like a default DataSource with default name..

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Instead of a listener, you could do the same using a data provider method itself by injecting the Method as parameter and have a default case.

Comment: any example available?

Comment: @DmitryAlexandrov Not sure if examples are available. This approach is something which I had tried some time back.

Comment: Still I wonder.. if there is a method to programmatically add DataProvider to a test class via listener?